Solitaire with the long middle column
This game was taught to me years ago, using a regular deck of cards.
Setup:

Columns 1,2,3: lay 1 card face up
Column 4: 6 cards down and the 7th up
Columns 5,6,7: 1 up.
The very next card goes up to the foundation and that is your starting number.

Play:

The foundation pile alternate between red and black going up,
the columns alternate between red and black going down
Column 4: can ONLY be played in the foundation.
Also you can only go through the deck once


At the opening deal, are there any face-down cards under the face-up cards in columns 1-3 and 5-7, or is each face-up card the only card in its column? Does the foundation roll back to A once you play K? Is there only one foundation pile, and if so, how do you switch from red-A, black-2 to black-A, red-2?

No face down cards in columns 1-3 & 5-7. There is 4 foundation piles and they round the clock so if the starting card is a 5 it will go 5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A,2,3,4
